# Oracle ODBC: Why are national characters changed to Latin equivalent in SELECT result

Tags: oracle, odbc, regional-settings

I have Oracle 11 database to which I connect using both JDBC and ODBC. JDBC works well, but in ODBC all Polish letters in `SELECT` result are changed to Latin equivalent, for example `ą` -> `a`, `Ó` -> `O` etc. I tested it with my application and simple Python program that uses `odbc` module. The same value from database is returned as:

```
ZAMOŚĆ - by JDBC
ZAMOSC - by ODBC
```

My environment:

DB server: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Client machine:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit
- Oracle clients in 32 bit and 64 bit versions in: `c:\Oracle\Ora1120_32bit` and `c:\Oracle\Ora1120_64bit`
- ODBC manager reports Oracle driver version as: 11.02.00.01

I think that all locales are set to Poland/Polish, but they are not visible
by `SET` command line utility.

Anybody knows what ODBC or environment setting is responsible for translation of Polish letters into Latin equivalents?

Comment: What is the value of your NLS_LANG ? since you're on windows it is set in the registry (probably HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> ORACLE -> YOUR_HOME -> NLS_LANG)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the value of the client character set is not the same in both cases. Can you check the value of your NLS_LANG setting:

- since you are on Windows, it should be set in the registry (probably HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> ORACLE -> YOUR_HOME -> NLS_LANG)
- you've found that this doesn't solve your problem, however adding an environment variable NLS_LANG did work !

Comment: Yes, `NLS_LANG` was set to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252` in registry (in two locations: one for 32 bit and one for 64 bit). I replaced registry settings to: `POLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250`, restarted machine but it not helped. Then I added `NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.EE8MSWIN1250` to machine environment and it helped. This machine was configured with American locales when Oracle client was installed.